# MQ Custom Docker Image - MQM Group Not Found

Tags: dockerfile, ibm-mq

**Description:** Getting the following error when running a docker build. I thought mqm group would be automatically created by default. Doesn't mention otherwise in the site link below. Can someone else try this?

**System Notes**:(VS Code- Docker build), windows machine.

**Error:**
useradd: group 'mqm' does not exist

Reference site for instructions:
[IBM MQ Customer Docker Image Instructions](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-docker/blob/master/README.md#customizing-the-queue-manager-configuration)

```
Docker File:
FROM ibmcom/mq
USER root
RUN useradd alice -G mqm && \
    echo alice:passw0rd | chpasswd
USER mqm
COPY 20-config.mqsc /etc/mqm/
```

Comment: Looks similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373195/ibmcom-mq-docker-image-backward-compatibility-issue#comment108710567_61373195

Comment: The IBM MQ support monitors the GIT issues, so it is probably better to go that route as suggested in the comment I linked to.

Comment: I have created an issue against there GitHub repo - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/issues/400

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [ibmcom/mq docker image backward compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373195/ibmcom-mq-docker-image-backward-compatibility-issue/62192274#62192274)

From 9.1.5 the container does not use OS based users or groups. This is to conform to cloud best practices.  Instead a file based system is being used. This is so that when you roll-out the container in a cloud into production you can switch to an LDAP based system.

The 9.1.5 container uses htpasswd, with the relevant file in /etc/mqm/

For development, if you are not going to create new users, then you can use the 9.1.5 container. If you want to create new users, then you can use 9.1.4 or earlier, or use htpasswd with bcrypt to create the users.

Comment: Hi, Is it mean that with 9.1.5 there is no way to use password authentication without LDAP?

Comment: No it doesn’t. You can use use htpasswd, although that should only be for development, and the restriction only applies to the configuration in the socket image.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a deprecated site apparently that's in the docker repo link. I guess its a problem with docker and they can`t remove it.   Please follow the instructions here. I had no issue.

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container