# ibmcom/mq. "useradd: group 'mqm' does not exist" error for new image version

Tags: ibm-mq

Recently I was able to run my app with ibmcom/mq:9.1.3.0-r3 and following Dockerfile definition:

```
FROM ibmcom/mq:9.1.3.0-r3
ENV LICENSE accept
ENV MQ_QMGR_NAME QM_MY_APP
USER root
RUN usermod -a -G mqm admin 
RUN usermod -a -G mqm root 
RUN useradd -g mqm my_user_id
ADD QueueManager /etc/mqm/myapp.mqsc
USER mqm
```

But now ibmcom/mq:9.1.3.0-r3 is not available on Dockerhub. When I pull and run other available docker versions (like 9.2.0.0-r1 and up) it throws following error because of commands in Dockerfile:

> useradd: group 'mqm' does not exist

I read the [MQ Custom Docker Image - MQM Group Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601607/mq-custom-docker-image-mqm-group-not-found), where the user "chughts" suggests to "use htpasswd with bcrypt to create the users."

Does anyone knows, how to use htpasswd to create the users in mq?
Thanks a lot for Your support in advance!

EDIT: I need to create an user via htpasswr for debug and local tests only. In production envirounment the qm's default user settings is used.

Comment: How are you authenticating,  is it via password or cert?

Comment: In ibmcom/mq:9.1.3.0-r3 my client apps used (blank) password to write/read queue messages from qmanager.

Answer (score 0):

The developer configuration of the container, does it using go modules.

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/master/cmd/runmqdevserver/main.go

It looks up the password from the environment setting, then runs

```golang
    appPassword, set := os.LookupEnv("MQ_APP_PASSWORD")
    if set {
        err = htpasswd.SetPassword("app", appPassword, false)
        if err != nil {
            logTerminationf("Error setting app password: %v", err)
            return err
        }
    }
```

The package `htpasswd` is in https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/master/internal/htpasswd/htpasswd.go

which has a `SetPassword` function

```golang
// SetPassword sets encrypted password for the user into htpasswd file
func SetPassword(user string, password string, isTest bool) error {
   ...
```

which right at the end saves the encrypted password

```golang
    // Update the password file
    return passwords.updateHtPasswordFile(isTest)
```

which does

```golang
func (htpfile mapHtPasswd) updateHtPasswordFile(isTest bool) error {

    file := "/etc/mqm/mq.htpasswd"
    if isTest {
        file = "my.htpasswd"
    }
    return ioutil.WriteFile(file, htpfile.GetBytes(), 0660)
}
```

This go code gets executed when building the developer image. I need to verify if this code stays on the machine, but you should be able to crib from the repo, to create your own go code that
invokes `htpasswd.SetPassword`, passing in your own user / password combinations.

> Update: Looks like the go runtime as well as the code is removed from
> the image, so you have options, but the easiest might be to  clone the
> repo, and build your own custom developer image version, with the
> extra users.
>
> Instructions for building a custom developer image can be found here - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/master/docs/building.md

Comment: Hi @chughts, thanks a lot for Your reply. I will check asap and let You know about my result. Best regards!