# Adding user permission denied in IBM MQ Docker

Tags: docker, unix, ibm-mq

As stated in https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-docker/blob/master/README.md when I add a user I get permission denied [ useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.]

It seems I can only add the user as root.
I switched as root user [ by providing "-u 0" ] while executing the docker container and tried. It is also not possible in that way.

Any idea to add an user inside mqm group of IBM MQ Docker container?

```
useradd user101 -G mqm && \
echo user101:passw0rd | chpasswd
```

Comment: Which version of IBM MQ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate of [ibmcom/mq. "useradd: group 'mqm' does not exist" error for new image version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349474/ibmcom-mq-useradd-group-mqm-does-not-exist-error-for-new-image-version/69407417#69407417)

[MQ Custom Docker Image - MQM Group Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601607/mq-custom-docker-image-mqm-group-not-found)

and

[ibmcom/mq docker image backward compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373195/ibmcom-mq-docker-image-backward-compatibility-issue/62192274#62192274)

In summary

> From 9.1.5 the container does not use OS based users or groups. This
> is to conform to cloud best practices. Instead a file based system is
> being used. This is so that when you roll-out the container in a cloud
> into production you can switch to an LDAP based system.
>
> From 9.1.5 container uses htpasswd, with the relevant file in /etc/mqm/