# IBM MQ image docker older versions

Tags: ibm-mq

I would like to pull IBM MQ from dockerhub but there are versions starting from 9, I need 8.
On dockerhub page https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq/ is link to the information how to build your own image if version 8 is necessary, but the resource is deprecated and dockerfile attached doesn't work. Could you please indicate any hint?

Using version 9 I get an error "Entity 'app' has insufficient authority to access object MYNAME [queue]. The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The following requested permissions are unauthorized: get/browse/inq". There were no such problems wirh version 8.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use 9?

Comment: application is built based on 8 and can not connect with newest image on docker

Comment: Versions are backward and forward compatible.  There should be no reason a app compiled against MQ v8.0 would not work against a MQ v9.0 or MQ v9.1 docer image.  What errors do you get when you try this combination.

Comment: <Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue://MYQUEUE/MYNAME' - trying to recover. Cause: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'MYNAME'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').>

Comment: I've tried alter qmgr chlauth(disabled) but still connection doesn't work

Comment: and with pulled version 8 from dockerhub everything was working

Comment: 2035 will require you look at the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG to check why it failed.  2035 on the client side is very general and looking at the Qmgr error logs will narrow it down to the specific cause.  Likely a setting difference between your v8 config and your v9 config, but nothing that can't be fixed by altering the config.

Comment: I've found the message: "Entity 'app' has insufficient authority to access object MYNAME [queue] " this user has privileges to connect and inquire, it's not enough I see.

Comment: That same message will usually tell the specific authority that is lacking.  You can edit your quest and paste the log entry into the question surrounded by ``` on the line above and below to show what you are getting.

Comment: What is the full error?  The same message should state what is missing. Something like `The following requested permissions are unauthorized: put`

Comment: "The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The
following requested permissions are unauthorized: get/browse/inq" But in config file i have "DEFINE QLOCAL (MYNAME)
SET AUTHREC PROFILE('MYNAME') OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP('mqclient') AUTHADD(BROWSE, GET, PUT, INQ)"

Comment: Is the `app` user a part of the `mqclient` group?   If not that would account for the difference.  You could try setting a principal `AUTHREC` instead of a group entry.

Comment: I have SRVCONN settled in that way, what I'm misisng? DEFINE CHANNEL(MINE.TCP.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) MCAUSER('app') REPLACE
SET CHLAUTH(MINE.TCP.SVRCONN) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS('*') USERSRC(CHANNEL) CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR) ACTION(REPLACE)

Comment: I'm asking if at the unix level is the `app` user part of the `mqclient` group.  On Linux you could run `id -a app` to see what groups it is a member of.

Comment: if ibm mq is in docker how can I check this?

Comment: There is a command let lets you run commands in the docker container, you can usually just start a bash and do it from there.  But as I mentioned, alternatively set your AUTHREC against the principal instead of the group.

Comment: I see you opened a new question if setting permission on the principal worked, I will right it up as a answer with more details.   Let me know please.

Comment: command 'id - a app' shows : user app not exists.

Comment: Ok.  Then there is no app user on that.

Comment: You said v9 is it v9.0 or v9.1?  I understand that the newest 9.1.5 docker images per openshift best practices have no user defined in the container.  I had also heard that there is a htpassword way to setup a user. See: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/issues/400

Comment: See this answer for some details on how to create the user at 9.1.5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373195/ibmcom-mq-docker-image-backward-compatibility-issue/62192274#62192274

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: I've added user app to queue. But app it is default user I'm not adding any special user.

Comment: Can you confirm that when you say "added user app to the queue" that you mean you "set your AUTHREC against the principal instead of the group."  meaning that you did the authorization against the user (principal) "app" not the group "mqclient"?

Comment: @JJ36 The default developer config includes auth records for the app user to connect to the DEV.* queue resources. Assuming you have not extended the default MQSC setup, it could be worth checking you can put to DEV.QUEUE.1

This tutorial might also be helpful as it explains the dev config for Ubuntu users https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-ubuntu